# Android Local notifications from background don't have a title

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, localnotification

Using [this plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) in an Ionic project I have been able to get local notifications going when a GCM push arrives (using ngCordova and the appropriate plugin).

The code flows a little something like this:

Inside the scope of an abstract app controller the pushNotification is set-up with an ecb that references a global `onNotification` function (outside of angular scope all together) there a localNotification is added.

Inside the angular scope an onclick handler is declared to lead the user to the right view.

The problem is that when the app is **not** in foreground, the following unwanted behaviours can be observed:

- The title of the notification is not displayed (even when hardcoded)
- The desired sound does not play (the device only vibrates)
- When the app comes to foreground, the onclick notification is not fired.

My notification code looks like this:

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
  message:    e.payload.message,
  title:      e.payload.activity.name,
  sound:      'android.resource://' + package_name + '/raw/bounce',
  json:       JSON.stringify(e.payload),
  autoCancel: true,
});
```

Any clues as to what is going on?

---

**FIXED**: As it turns out, the event callback is never called when the app is in the background and the push notification is turned into a local notifaction - a feature I had overlooked. Thank you all for your time and trouble :/

Comment: Your code snippet makes me guess you didn't try a fixed string for the title property. You're sure `e.payload.activity.name` has a value?

Comment: Yes, I am sure (99%) it has a value; and yes I did try it with a hard coded value - no show when the app is not in foreground.

Comment: Any relation to this:https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/42 ?

Comment: @Slartibartfast tis quite a long read; but there may be something of interest in there... Thx for pointing that out!

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

> public void notifyUser(){
>
> ```
>     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
>
>     Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, SomeActivity.class);
>
>     //use the flag FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to override any notification already there
>     PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>
>     Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Some Text", System.currentTimeMillis());
>     notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
>
>     notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "This is a notification Title", "Notification Text", contentIntent);
>     //10 is a random number I chose to act as the id for this notification
>     notificationManager.notify(10, notification);   }
> ```

Comment: Where exactly would I put this snippet of code in my cordova/ionic project?